# How to calculate ahead or behind branchs

Tags: libgit2sharp

Use `libgit2sharp`, how to calculate `ahead` or `behind` metrics. like this page https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/branches

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to calculate ahead or behind metrics

Each `Branch` bears a `TrackingDetails` property. This property exposes `AheadBy` and `BehindBy` nullable values (null will be returned when the branch has no upstream configuration or if the upstream branch does not exist).

Those values will represent the number of commits the local branch is ahead/behind compared to the upstream branch (ie. the remote branch being tracked).

This outputs similar results than `git status -sb`

> like this page https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/branches

This page actually compares each branch of the upstream (ie. the one hosted on GitHub) repository against the current tip of the remote `HEAD`. This feature (comparing two local branches) is not available in LibGit2Sharp.

Provided you're interested with it, please feel free to **[open a feature request](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)**.

### Update

A pull request (see **[#564](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/564)**) introducing a new method `repo.ObjectDatabase.CalculateHistoryDivergence(Commit, Commit)` is cooking up.

This will allow the user to determine the ahead-by and behind-by counts, along with the merge-base that's been used to calculate those distances.

Comment: Maybe I understand what is `tracking branch`. But in github branches pages is calculate between each branches and a base branch (master, vNext)

Comment: *is calculate between each branches and a base branch (master, vNext)* -> Indeed, in this case the remote HEAD is the **vNext** branch (which **[has been set as the default HEAD branch](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch)**)

Comment: Yeah, I know github can set HEAD branch

Comment: Thanks @nulltoken  repo.ObjectDatabase.CalculateHistoryDivergence is what I needed :)

Answer (score 3):

For those searching (as of pygit2 v 0.27.4), the API is `ahead_behind`.

Sample code gist:

```
    import pygit2
    repo = pygit2.Repository('your-repo-path')

    upstream_head = repo.revparse_single('origin/HEAD')
    local_head    = repo.revparse_single('HEAD')

    diff = repo.ahead_behind(local_head.id, upstream_head.id)
```